# Attach .java file as source for .jar in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to step through a project in IntelliJ. As part of that, I need to force step into a jar. That causes IntelliJ to decompile the jar for me and show me the code that will be run, but it doesn't let me actually step through that decompiled code - if I click any of the step buttons, it just steps all the way until control exits the decompiled jar.

Looking around, it looks like a possible solution to allow me to actually step through the code is to attach the source code. I have the source code, as a .java file, for the specific class that I'd like to step into, but IntelliJ doesn't seem to be allowing me to add .java files as source.

So how can I get a .java file attached as source for a .jar in IntelliJ? Or, if that's not the right approach, how can I go about using the stepper within a decompiled class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your Java file into a correct directory structure. For example, suppose you have a class com.mypackage.MyClass in myjar.jar. Then you need to create the following structure:

```
myjar
  com
    mypackage
      MyClass.java
```

Once you do that, attach the "myjar" directory as a source for your .jar file, and you'll see the correct source code while debugging.