# Proper way to configure IntelliJ to use source code for decompiled jar

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jar

I have been trying to figure this one out for a bit, not coming up with the right approach.  I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243315/attach-java-file-as-source-for-jar-in-intellij), which I'd already tried, but it's not working quite right.. using IntelliJ EAP 142.4675.3

What I am trying to do, is to debug a junit test using a jar (extending the Provider class) file I've placed into JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext. I want that jar to be debuggable as well.

The problem is, if I attach my source directory as the source for a jar, then, in a stack trace, when I click the named file (containing a method I wish to view), IntelliJ asks me to choose between two of the same file, presumably because it knows about the source (it's in a module in my project) and it's also been told about the source via the jar source path I added.

I tried adding the provider.jar to the project module dependencies tab, which caused intellij no end of grief.  Reverted back to having it in jre\lib\ext, and, in the Platform Settings->SDKs->1.8->Sourcepath tab, I added the module sourcepath.  This lets intellij step into the .java file for the jar, vs the .class file, but, when it does so, I now get a banner at the top of my code windows which says "Alternative source available for the class xxx" and there's a combobox at the RHS with the module name listed twice (in the latest EAP, it actually lists the module and the jar [same name as module, with .jar]).  And, as mentioned earlier, the IDE asks which which (of the very same) file I wish to edit when I click a file in the stack trace.

Clearly, there is something not quite right.. what am I missing?  I find it odd that the ide will not open the source code when stepping into the jar until I attach the code as above, but, when I do, it sees it twice.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/dependencies-tab.html is worth a read I think. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

Comment: The first link pretty much sums up the answer in the q I linked to... the second, really pooches things.  I removed the jar from the jre\lib\ext dir, then added a copy via the dependencies tab, runtime scope.  Now, when running the junit test, intellij is complaining that it cannot validate a jar in out\production\blahblah.

Answer (score 0):

So let's start from scratch:

- File > New Project, choose "Java Module", fill the form: [image: capture1]
- Bypass the form asking about the kind of project (webapp etc) by clicking on "finish"
- you now have a project with a `src` dir:[image: capture2]
- right click the `32910506` directory and choose "New" then "Directory" and create a new directory named lib.
- drag and drop your 2 jars (sources and code) to this directory (I will use [`common-lang`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for this example), beware to copy, not move:
  [image: capture3]
- now right click on `src`, choose "New", "Java class", name it `App`:
  [image: capture4]
- right click your "code jar" and choose "Add as library":
  [image: capture5]
- in `App` type `psvm` then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get a `main` and fill it like this:
  [image: capture6]
- right click on your "code jar" and choose "Open library settings":
  [image: capture7]
- click "+" and choose "Attach file or directory" and select your "sources jar":
  [image: capture8]
- Now if your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on `random` in App, you should end up to the method source:
  [image: capture9]
- Put a break point in the `random` method:

[image: capture10]

- Now right click `App`, choose "Debug App.main()", you should end up to the previous breakpoint:
  [image: capture11]
  [image: capture12]

---

Used: idea 12.1.6 under linux